# START_STICKY for IntentService

Tags: android, service, android-service, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have seen many android Service examples where return START_STICKY is used to start an app on boot but is there anyway I can use the same for IntentService. I understand that Service method runs on the main UI thread and the IntentService as a separate thread.

1. But how exactly can they be invoked and why is it not possible to start IntentService on boot. Since IntentService runs on a separate thread we have more control over it if i'm not worng.
2. I tried using onStartCommand in IntentService but my app crashes on boot even though it works perfectly fine when started manually. Can we override onStartCommand in IntentService ?

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 8):

Running at boot and `START_STICKY` have nothing to do with one another - `START_STICKY` is a flag to determine what should happen if your service is killed by Android.

`IntentService` is designed to process an incoming intent (via `handleIntent`) and stop immediately after. As seen in the [source of IntentService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java), it already handles `onStartCommand` appropriately.

As long as you are requesting

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and have the correct intent-filter on your `IntentService`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then your service will get called on boot complete.

(The one exception is if your app is installed on an SD card as per [install location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html))